# How can I make sure that the title of a Terminal tab/window is identical to the command I typed

Tags: terminal, command-line, bash

I noticed that for aliases etc the title of a Terminal tab/window often isn't the same as the command I typed. This is sometimes confusing, especially for long-running processes with similar names.

So how can I configure `bash`/Terminal in a way which ensures that the window title always reflects the command as typed?

Examples:

- When I type `python -m SimpleHTTPServer` and press <kbd>Return</kbd> in a Terminal window, the tab of that Terminal window should show "python -m SimpleHTTPServer" immediately.
- When I type `flushdns`, which is my alias for `sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder;sudo killall mDNSResponderHelper;sudo dscacheutil -flushcache` and press <kbd>Return</kbd> in a Terminal window, the tab of that Terminal window should show "flushdns" immediately.

What I tried:

I tried modifying `PS4` to run a command. This works, however it also prints a lot of other garbage, like getting the current git branch and other commands I put in my `PS1`. If there's a way for `PS4` to only run scripts and not output anything (not even line breaks) I'm fine with that too as a solution.

I also tried the various options under Preferences > Profiles > Tab, but it does not allow showing the literal command I just entered.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish here? Right now you list a lot of things you have (unsuccessfully) tried, but the goal is rather vague. Are you looking for a way to change the tab/window title while a process is running, for ways to set it individually *before* a process gets launched, or for something else? Can you clarify, ideally with some examples?

Comment: @nohillside your interpretation is correct. I rephrased the first sentence and made it bold because that's the main thing I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: Still not clear....  you want to capture the *input* of a command?  For example, the input could be a text file.  How would this be beneficial as the Terminal tab

Comment: What you want to do is clear, *why* you want to do it, and what you want to accomplish isn‘t. Having more details on that might help.

Comment: @Allan the *input* as in, the exact command(s) that I typed in a Terminal. I clarified that bit with two examples.

Comment: @nohillside The reason is I often have multiple tabs open with long-running processes. If tabs show the process that they are running, or ran last, it would be easy for me to recognize the tabs from the title alone.

Comment: Thanks for the edits. So basically your question is "How can I make sure that the title of a Terminal tab/window is identical to the command I typed", correct?

Comment: @nohillside yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

macOS Catalina (10.15) now uses [Zsh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z_shell), which makes this really easy.

Show the currently running / last run command by disabling auto_title and adding a `preexec` hook:

```
# File: ~/.zshrc

DISABLE_AUTO_TITLE="true"

preexec() {
    printf "\e]1;${1}\a"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Open a Terminal window and go to preferences. Click on Profiles and select Window from the pane, In the Window pane there is an option to show active process name. Check that box and the one under it that says arguments. See image below.

[image]

Comment: This doesn't show the alias name for aliased commands though